# stop people stealing files from site

Tags: php

I'm creating a job site where employees will be uploading resume/CV.

How can I stop others from viewing other people's resume/CV and stop search engines from indexing this content?

Comment: Just block the URL `http://YourSite/downloadAllResumes`

Comment: using htaccess or using different methods

Comment: @Lalajee, It depends on your needs and circumstances, which you haven't posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an authentication system, and do not present the public url to the downloader.
For example, you create a table like:

```
file_name    | file_path         |  file_code
-------------------------------------------------------
My picture   | /var/docs/img.jpg | kljsldjalksdqhq1218
```

And after the user is logged in (and meets the criteria you defined) you present him with the download link:

http://yoursite.com/index.php?page=download&file=kljsldjalksdqhq1218

Then you query the database, check the correct association, and then you read the file - which resides outside the document root btw using `file_get_contents()` for example and present it as an octet-stream, or another appropriate MIME for the file type, to force the file download; something along the lines of:

```
header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($file));
```

Comment: In addition to this, never keep files on your system named the same as the file that the user uploaded.  You can hang onto that file name so that when the user downloads it later, you can return it, but file names on your local system should be random, and have no extension.

Comment: what I have down is upload the file with time as name and with no exe at the end. this the link domain.com/download.php?id=2. this then checks the id in table and user can download the file. I have done same as what you wrote in this response. Can my files still be taken from my server or not.

Answer (score 10):

Simple.  Don't make the files available without some authentication.

Comment: and add `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` to the meta of the relevant pages.

Comment: you have to login to see the files but i wont to hide my save path from employers and employees.

Comment: Maybe a hint of authorization as well?

Comment: Just so you know, file system paths and resource URLs don't have to align.  In fact, it wasn't intended that they be related at all -- it just happens to be an easy way to serve static files.  You can rearrange your URL space any way you like, even having them hidden above the document root...problem is, if a user can get to `/files/resume001.pdf`, does it really matter that its URL is `/resumes/001`?  Either way, without proper authentication/authorization, you're handing people access.

Comment: Lalajee, What do you mean?  You should be saving your files outside of the web root anyway.  This is what @cHao is getting at.